# Php array isn't the same when I hardcode it as it is to when I get it from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to get a php array containing picname where nsfwlevel == x.
If I roll a 0 pic 0 loads (ecchi.jpg) from the array fine. But if I roll a 1 I get:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 on `line 38 ($i = rand(0, count($bg)-1);)`
Stil count($bg) returns 2 so there should be something there.

If I add

```
 //$bg = array('ecchi.jpg', 'bg3.jpg');
```

before $i = rand(... it works fine so there's probably something wrong with the way I'm getting the array from mysql or something about how I'm processing it.

My database looks like the following:

```
| picid | picname | nsfwlevel |   
|   1   | ecchi.jpg|     1    |   
|   2   | bg3.jpg |      1    |

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

$db = mysql_select_db("animeclub", $connection);
if{...}
elseif($_SESSION['nsfwlevel'] == 1){


$query = mysql_query("SELECT picname from backgrounds WHERE nsfwlevel='0'", $connection);
$backgroundArray = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$bg = $backgroundArray; 
}
elseif{...}
mysql_close($connection);
$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1);
$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]";
```

Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: 1) Better migrating mysql_* function (deprecated) to mysqli_* or pdo. 2) you need for each row of $backgroundArray (while $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) to put in on your array, then your rand will work, you hare using only the first row as it for now.

Comment: You set `$bg` in one `if-else` branch, but count($bg) in the second one (in `else` one).

Comment: @panther I had $bg = $backgroundArray; in each one but I've moved it so I have it after all the if's right before mysql_close. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a loop to fetch all data :

```
$bg = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT picname from backgrounds WHERE nsfwlevel='0'", $connection);

while ($backgroundArray = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    $bg[] = $backgroundArray['picname'];
```